# reference the scope of a dialog controller's parent

Tags: angularjs

I've created a component that contains a button inside an ng-form and when I click on this button an dialog will be oppened, like this:

```
.component('colorPicker', {
            bindings: {},
            require: {
                parent: '?^form'
            },
            templateUrl: 'color-picker-component.html',
            controller: 'ColorPickerController',
            controllerAs: 'colorPickerCtrl'
    });
```

**color-picker-component.html :**

```
<ng-form name="{{colorPickerCtrl.formName}}">
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-raised" ng-click=colorPickerCtrl.showDialog()>
    <md-icon>format_color_fill</md-icon>
    <md-tooltip>Sélectionner une couleur</md-tooltip>
</md-button>
</ng-form>
```

**ColorPickerController :**

```
function ColorPickerController($scope, $mdDialog, $rootScope) {

        var vm          = this;
        vm.formName     = "colorPicker_Form";

        vm.hideDialog = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        vm.showDialog = function () {
            $mdDialog.show({
                bindToController: true,
                preserveScope: true,
                templateUrl:  'color-picker-dialog.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                controller: 'ColorPickerDialogController',
                controllerAs: 'colorPickerDGCtrl',
                locals: {
                    parentScope: vm
                }
            });
        };

    }
```

But when I call `parentScope` inside the `ColorPickerDialogController` I get an undefined value.

So how can I reference the `ColorPickerController` scope inside the `ColorPickerDialogController` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your dialogController

```
$scope.$parent.someProperty
```